# What is "better" : (x=x) or (void(x)) for unused parameters?

Tags: c, performance, variables, memory, void

Well we all know that sometimes we get parameters to a function but we don't really use them.

We don't want to get any compiler warnings so we need to somehow "use" but not really use those parameters.

**2 options are available to us:**

> `#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)`

> `#define UNUSED(x) (x=x)`

and in general,
to define `(x=x)` or `void(x)` in a function, even without `#define`.

*The question is:*

Which one of these is "better"?

Better for performance (quicker), memory allocation(if any), anything you can think about speaking technically.

Comment: Can I suggest `__attribute__((unused))` instead? It's a compiler level option, might be faster than the above.

Comment: If it is a function parameter you can comment out the name to avoid a warning or error and make it clear the parameter is not used. `int foo(int i, int /* unused */) { ... }` Refactoring to completely remove the unused parameter is a good idea too.

Comment: @RetiredNinja oh that's pretty cool, didn't know it. Pretty cool that's a comment considered by the compiler as "some way you use with the parameter".

Comment: What @RetiredNinja suggests should generally not work if you are using sensible compiler warnings and treat them as errors.

Comment: The `(void)(unused_var)` is essentially a NOP that suppresses the `-Wunused` warning. The `x = x;` would be an actual assignment unless optimized away by the compiler. So from that standpoint, the cast to `void` is guaranteed to suppress the unused warning in a consistent manner, while how the assignment is treated would be implementation dependent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`(void)x` is part of the standard, so it should be better. You won't get compilers/linters warnings when you use it. It is also portable, unlike implementation-specific solutions like `__attribute__((unused))` and it will not generate any code. `x = x` may generate warnings.

An example regarding the warnings that can be emitted for `x=x`:

```c
int foo(int bar)
{
    bar = bar;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    return foo(2);
}
```

Compiling the above code with `-Wall` (or just `-Wself-assign`) with Clang 10 triggers the following warning:

```
$ clang test.c -Wall
test.c:3:9: warning: explicitly assigning value of variable of type 'int' to itself [-Wself-assign]
    bar = bar;
    ~~~ ^ ~~~
```

Same goes for linters like `cppcheck`:

```
$ cppcheck test.c --enable=all
Checking test.c ...
test.c:3:9: warning: Redundant assignment of 'bar' to itself. [selfAssignment]
    bar = bar;
        ^
test.c:3:9: style: Variable 'bar' is assigned a value that is never used. [unreadVariable]
    bar = bar;
        ^
```

Of course, these depend on the tools you use and the warnings you enable, so it may or may not generate warnings, but casting an expression to `void` will never generate these kind of warnings.

Comment: I'm unsure on the "may generate warnings" part, the assignment should suppress the warning consistently, the issue is whether it is done by the compiler optimizing away the assignment, or whether the actual assignment occurs costing a meager instruction. The answer to the latter will likely depend on the optimization options provided, but the warning will be suppressed either way. Other than that, I agree with the result.

Comment: @David C. Rankin I edited my answer to clarify the "may generate warnings" part.

Comment: Much better explanation. I am no longer unsure `:)`

Answer (score 2):

> Which one of these is "better"?

```
#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)
```

Because it's pretty much standard for what you're doing anyway.

> Better for performance (quicker), memory allocation(if any), anything you can think about speaking technically.

If you have optimization activated, which you should if you care about performance, these things will be optimized away anyway.